# Cannot open backup device, Operating system error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.)

Tags: sql, sql-server, centos7

Hice un respaldo de la base de datos en un servidor Windows, e intento restaurarlo en Centos con **mssql-cmd** y desde **dbeaver**, ambos me mandan el mismo error:

> Cannot open backup device '/var/opt/mssql/backup/Respaldo.bak'. Operating system error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.).

Este es el query con el que lo intente.

```
RESTORE DATABASE QualitzPalmissCentos FROM DISK = '/var/opt/mssql/backup/RespaldoQualitz.bak' 
WITH MOVE 'RespaldoQualitz' TO '/var/opt/mssql/data/QualitzPalmissCentos.mdf', 
MOVE 'RespaldoQualitz_Log' TO '/var/opt/mssql/data/QualitzPalmissCentos_Log.ldf'
```

Queda aclarar que soy `root` y tengo permisos `777` en la carpeta.

Comment: No estoy seguro de como funcionan los permisos en Linux, pero en Windows la cuenta de SQL Server puede ser distinta a la del usuario. ¿Has revisado eso?

Comment: Al correr el query, no importa tu usuario root sino el usuario que corre el proceso de MSSQL. Lo otro, puede que /backup tenga 777 pero asegúrate que el usuario que comento tenga acceso a *toda la ruta*. Si no puede ver /var/opt/mssql/, no va a ver nunca `/backup` por más permisos que le pongas